# Cookie can't be accessed from any other part of my site. How can I fix this?

Tags: php, cookies, dns

The way I've built my PHP site frequently uses commands such as

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/scripts/create_comment_section.php"); ?>
```

to string together a series of separate pages into one whole. Perhaps this may the the root of the following problem? I've been reading tutorials and banging my head against the wall for an hour, but to no avail.

In the root directory (/index.php) of a website I'm using to practice coding, I've defined a cookie that lasts for 2 minutes. I've defined it before the file that contains all my `<!doctype>` and `<head>` stuff, is included.

summon.endgame.pk/index.php:

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "Anna Cake";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (60 * 2), "/", ".endgame.pk"); // 60 seconds x 2 = 2 mins
?>

<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/html_head.html"); ?>
<body>

<!-- ✎ background image  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<img src="/img/background-top.jpg" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:1">

<!-- ✎ login panel  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/homepage/login.html"); ?>

<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/homepage/article_intro.html"); ?>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/homepage/article_news.html"); ?>

<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/html_foot.html"); ?>
```

Every page on my website contains the file /homepage/login.html which checks to see if the cookie has been set:

```
<!-- login panel -->
<div class="table1" style="position: absolute; top: -30px; left: 800px; width:400px; height: 200px; z-index: 2; padding: 35px 15px 15px 15px;">
<span class="title1">Login</span>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";   } 
else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];    }
?>

</div>
```

When I go to my homepage (where the cookie was first sent - index.html) and refresh that page twice, (sending the cookie out and checking it), it shows up perfectly. However, when I try to go to any other part of my website (such as summon.endgame.pk/summon_chance) and try to read that cookie .... it says it has not been set.

This is my first time tying to use cookies ... I've been reading tutorials for hours and I cannot understand why it's not working across the other pages since I've defined it in the very index of the site.

```
$cookie_value, time() + (60 * 2), "/", ".endgame.pk")
```

I've even added the "/" to specify all the sub folders, and the "." before my domain name to make sure...

Please help .. stackoverflow is my last resort!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake!

The cookie itself was written correctly and now it works. The problem was that I defined the variables

```
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "Anna Cake";
```

in one file and tried to use them again in a completely different file that didn't even have the 1st one included. Instead of trying to use those same variables again to check for the cookie (which WAS working perfectly, already!) I've changed the code that tests to see if the cookie has been recorded from:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";   } 
else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];    }
?>
```

to

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
    echo "Cookie named 'user' is not set!";   } 
else {
    echo "Cookie 'user' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE['user'];    }
?>
```

now it returns "Anna Cake" all throughout my website, even if the cookie was only defined in the index page.